# Android posting data to server using HTTPPOST after encoding using BASE64

Tags: android, web

I am trying to send data to server using `HTTPPOST`. I have encoded username and password using `BASE64.encodetoString()`. But I am unable to post the data. There is no error but I am getting **400 or 404 response** code every time. The code is successfully executed when done in Java, but it is not working as expected in android. Please help me.

Here is the code I am using:

```
public void  getLoginInfo()
{
   String user="xxxx@gmail.com";
   String password="1234xyz";

     // Creating HTTP client
       HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Creating HTTP Post
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

       // String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((user + ":" + password).getBytes(),0);
        // Building post parameters
        // key and value pair

        byte[] data=(user+":"+password).getBytes();
        String base64EncodedCredentials =Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
        String httpheader="Basic "+base64EncodedCredentials;
        System.out.println("httpheader "+httpheader);
       /* List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "nishanth.s@giwitservices.com"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password","100006438166763hbsV1v0"));*/
        // Url Encoding the POST parameters


        // Making HTTP Request
      //  try {
            try {
                httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", httpheader);
                //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                 System.out.println("response test "+response.toString());
                 System.out.println("response code "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                 String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
                 System.out.println("respones "+the_string_response);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                       
}
```

Comment: Is the server running in your local or it's in internet?

Comment: You use ip address or url to post?

Comment: I really hope for you, that these provided credentials are not your real ones ... otherwise, it's time to change your password :)

Comment: Server is running on internet @karthick

Comment: I used JSON Url to post the data @PANDA

Comment: I didn't provide the real credentials in the question, but the text is same format @GeneSys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `BASE64.DEFAULT`, try to use `BASE64.NO_WRAP`. That would help you in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
String base64EncodedCredentials =Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

To this:

```
String base64EncodedCredentials =Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP|Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got the response code 200 now. I've been trying this since 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this :

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key_of_data", data));            

HttpPost oHttpPost = new HttpPost(your_url);
oHttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Instead of using **Base64** encoding

Comment: I used this also you can see this in the commented code, but this is also not working